# I know this is basic

Tags: c++, scope, int, global

(This is the question asked of me.)
What is the output from the following program? Explain your results.

```
int val = 20;

int func1()
{
  int val = 5;
  return val;
}

int func2()
{
  return val;
}

int main()
{
  // (1)
  cout << func1() << endl;

  // (2)
  cout << func2() << endl;
}

Output::

5
20
```

---I am assuming it is like this because:---

- func1 changes val from 20 to 5.
- func2 changes nothing.
- I believe the val is modified by each function and stored separately.

Could someone explain this, tell me what subject I should look at?

Comment: Remove the `int` keyword in `func1`, and you have an assignment (which changes the global variable's value) instead of a declaration (which creates a new local `var` and initialises it to 5).

Comment: Basic, no. That's all C++.  Good on you for running the program. It's depressing how many people asking similar questions don't bother.

Comment: Try editing your problem title to give it some meaningful meaning.

Answer (score 3):

```
int val = 20;

int func1()
{
  int val = 5;
  return val;
}
```

The above creates **two** variables named `val`. One is global, and the other is local to scope of `func1`.
When you are inside the scope of `func1`, the local `val` hides the global one. You therefore do not change the value of the global variable, and simply return what you stored in the local `val`.

```
int func2()
{
  return val;
}
```

`func2` returns the value of the global variable (which wasn't changed). And that is why you see the output you noted.

If you want to refer to the global variable, despite having a local, you can use the scope resolution operator `::`.

```
int val = 20;

int func1()
{
  int val = 5;
  ::val = 10;
  return val;
}
```

The above will set the global `val` to 10.

Answer (score 2):

> func1 changes val from 20 to 5.

No, it is returning the local variable as it is. Not changing the global var. Innermost scoped var overtakes outer var with same name.

> func2 changes nothing.

True. It is returning the global var without change. This function call be may optimised away by compiler altogether.

> I believe the val is modified by each function and stored separately.

Incorrect, none of the function is doing any change to value.

Further, have a look at storyteller answer for scope resolution operator :: concepts.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring val as 20 at a global level, so func2() will just return that.

In func1(), you declare val as 5, then return that. The global variable is ignored for the scope of the method.

If you are confused about this, I would read up on scope.

Answer (score 1):

func1 creates a local variable with value 5 and returns it. The global variable remains unchanged.

func2 return the global variable whose value is 20.

Answer (score 1):

> func1 changes val from 20 to 5

Incorrect.

`func1` uses a local variable named `val` whose value is `5`. It does not change the value of the global variable of the same name.

> func2 changes nothing.

Correct. It just returns the value of the global variable `val`.

> I believe the val is modified by each function and stored separately.

Incorrect. Neither function, as posted, modifies the global variable `val`. The global value is not stored separately for each function. `func1` uses a local variable of the same name and does not touch the global variable at all. `func2` accesses the value of the global variable but does not modify it.

Answer (score 1):

*Let me tell you a story, assume you are living in a small town namely, SmallTown. Your neighboring town is, Hello. There is a coincidence too and that is the city you are living in is also named Hello. Now, your mother asks you to go to Hello and get some bread. What would be your first reaction? You will go to neighboring town, right. After a week you have to go to another city. Now, somebody asks you, "When are you going back to Hello?". Which "Hello" are you thinking about now? The city, right.*

To your problem,
The `int` variable you are going to access depends on your scope. If you are inside a function i.e., if your scope is local and there is local defined same name and same type variable, it will be accessed before the globally defined variable.

Both of the variables are different and will have different memory addresses, so NO,

> func1 changes val from 20 to 5

This is not true. Both are different just as the town and city.

Of course **func2 changes nothing**, as it looks for the `val` and reaches the global defined variable as if it was out of the city.

Again, no **I believe the val is modified by each function and stored separately**. And I think you know the answer to this now.